# Python Telegram Bot - InlineKeyboardButton needs to have 2 clicks instead of one when using a Conversation Handler

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to make a bot that will ask the user for some basic info. I am using the python-telegram-bot library (version 20.3) to make one: https://python-telegram-bot.org/

I am trying to use a Conversation Handler to start the whole conversation:

```
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
            GENDER : [
                    MessageHandler(filters=filters.ALL, callback=gender),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(callback=gender_callback)
                ],
            AGE: [CallbackQueryHandler(callback=age)],
            RACE : [
                MessageHandler(filters=filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, callback=race),
                CallbackQueryHandler(callback=race_callback)
            ],
            NUMBER: [CallbackQueryHandler(callback=number)],
            AREA: [MessageHandler(filters=filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, callback=area)],
            QUALIFICATION: [MessageHandler(filters=filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, callback=qualification)],
            SCHOOLS: [
                MessageHandler(filters=filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, callback=schools),
            ],
            TUTOR_TYPE: [
                MessageHandler(filters=filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, callback=tutor_type),
                CallbackQueryHandler(callback=tutor_type_callback)
            ],
            FINISH: [CallbackQueryHandler(callback=finish)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )
```

This is the definition of my conversation handler. The problem arises with the CallbackQueryHandler functions which are basically functions that are called when an inline button is pressed. The problem with this is that the bot recognizes the first button click, which means that the function handler is called and everything runs as normal. But to continue the conversation, i.e. go to the next step, I need to click any other button again. How can this be solved so that I click the desired button and the conversation goes to the next step without a need to click again.

Here is how the keyboard looks when I click the necessary button once:

[image]

This stays like so and I have to select the other button for the conversation to continue, even though the bot takes the Male value and saves it.
This is the code for the gender question:

```
async def gender(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """The user is asked to choose their gender."""
    name = update.message.text
    context.user_data["name"] = name

    button1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Male', callback_data='male')
    button2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Female', callback_data='female')
                                   
    # Create the keyboard markup
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [button1, button2]
        ]
    )

    await update.message.reply_text(
        text="Gender?",
        reply_markup=keyboard
    )

async def gender_callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Retrieve the value from the clicked button and take the next step."""
    selected_button = update.callback_query.data

    print(f"The selected button is {selected_button}")

    context.user_data["gender"] = selected_button
    
    return AGE
```

The gender_callback function is called when the button is pressed and the return AGE should return to the conversation handler and should continue the conversation. The print function inside gender_callback prints normally after the first click and doesn't print anything after the second click, which means that the code does what I want, but I need to click two different buttons to continue the conversation.

What do I need to do to make the conversation continue without having to click 2 different buttons? This is a problem for every single question that poses itself as an inline keyboard button.

I am doing this for a client and as such, I have to use the inlinekeyboardbutton and cannot use the replykeyboardmarkup.

I have to admit I did not try anything as I do not know how to solve this and the materials online are quite sparse and ChatGPT is having problems with this code as it was trained on older versions of this library (I believe so because it gives me functions that do not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. In `gender_callback` you do not call `await update.callback_query.answer()`, which leads to the "loading" icon still showing on the button.
2. You `return AGE` but do not tell the user what input you are expecting next. As a rule of thumb: before returning the next state you should give the user something to react to. Then the handler in the next state can handle that reacting.

Maybe this clears things up.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.